# Understanding the meaning of CheckHalt(X,X) in the proof of a theorem in Sussana Epp's Discrete Mathematics with applications

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, paradoxes

I have a very basic exposure to algorithms. I am a graduate in Mathematics. I was reading Halting Problem in the book Discrete Mathematics with applicationbs by Susanna Epp. It has a following theorem :

> **Theorem :** There is no computer algorithm that will accept any algorithm X and data set D as input and then will output "halts" or "loops forever" to indicate whether or not X terminates in a finite number of steps when X is run with data set D.
>
> **Proof :** Suppose there is an algorithm, call it CheckHalt, such that if an algorithm X and a data set D are input, then CheckHalt prints "halts" if X terminates in a finite number of steps when run with the data set D or "loops forever" if X does notterminate in a finite number of steps when run with data set D.
>
> *Now next lines are those which I don't understand in this proof*
>
> Observe that the sequence of characters making up an algorithm X can be regarded as a data set itself. Thus it is possible to consider running a CheckHalt with input (X,X).

So I have understood that CheckHalt essentially gets input as an algorithm X and a data set D. It tells whether if we run the algorithm X with that data set D as it's (X's) input, then X will halt or loop forever. Thus CheckHalt(X,D) seems good.

My question is how can an algorithm X have an input X itself i.e how can we call an algorithm as a data set?

What is the meaning of the sentence "sequence of characters making up an algorithm X"?

I can understand CheckHalt(X,D). But what is CheckHalt(X,X)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it talks about an algorithm X, it is talking about a set of instructions ... for example, when I tell you how to do addition of two numbers, I might say 'start with the two digits on the right, add those up, and write down the sum and the possibly carry-over. Then, ....'

Now, notice that these instructions are expressed in English, but I could have used any other language as well. Computers of course have their own language too, usually binary. Anyway, it is *some* language we ar using, and the computer program is a string of symbols following that language.

So, don't think of X as the actual 'running program', but rather as the *description* of what needs to be done: a program is just a description of a process, and only when the program is being executed will that process actually take place.

In sum: the algorithm/computer program X is a string of characters that happens to be a set of instructions.

But the 'data set' D is *any* kind of string of symbols. That of course does not mean that D is a set of instructions, but it *could* be.  Hence, you can use X as a specific kind of data set; a data set that happens to be a computer program.

And so we can pass X as an argument to the CheckHalt routine, which will treat the first argument X as a computer program, and the second argument (also X) as a string of symbols that the computer program X is supposed to work with (that is, CheckHalt is going to try and determine whether the computer program X, when it is being executed and will work on input symbol string X will halt or not)